# Finding the quotient set of relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, quotient-set

Let A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. We define (a,b)R(c,d)  iff 2|(a-c) ∧ 3|(b-d). R  is an equivalence relation on the set AXA. find the quotient set.

I got 2 equivalence classes - [(1,3)], [2,4]
how do I know I got every equivalence class if the set is too big to check manually?
and are there anymore?

Comment: $R$ would appear to be a relation on $A\times A$, not $A$, right?

Comment: yes I forgot to mention it's on AXA

Comment: Well, you specifically say it is a relation on $A$, which it isn't.

Comment: Which of your two classes would $(1,2)$ belong to?  Or $(2,2)$?

Comment: I guess they are not in either of them. So do I need to check each time I calculate an equivalence class that I have all the possible options for (a,b) in AXA?

Comment: Well, try thinking about it abstractly.  All that matters in the first slot is the parity (even or odd).  All that matters in the second slot is the remainder on division by $3$. Start there.

Comment: Either check, or find a way to prove every possible pair is in one of your equivalence classes. Hint: There are six equivalence classes.